# Check box in table header to check all checkboxes in other rows

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have a checkbox in my table header to select/unselect all checkboxes in the table.I tried to bind change/click event to that. same event is working for other check boxes but not for the check box on header. I am using MVC3 & KnockoutJS bindings. Added code part below.

```html
<tr class="cont-subhead trClinicList">
    <th class="tWidth10 textAlign">
        <input type="checkbox" id="selectAllCb" data-bind="event:{ change:function(){$root.ClickSelectAll();return true;} }"  />
</tr>
```

jQuery:

```
self.ClickSelectAll = function (data,event) {
    alert("method hit");
    if ($('#selectAllCb').is(':checked')) {
        for (var i = 0; i < self.AdminToolDetails().length; i++) {
            if (self.AdminToolDetails()[i].IsEnabled() && self.AdminToolDetails()[i].IsSelected() == false) {
                self.AdminToolDetails()[i].IsSelected(true);
            }
        }
    }

    else {
        for (var i = 0; i < self.AdminToolDetails().length; i++) {
            if (self.AdminToolDetails()[i].IsEnabled() && self.AdminToolDetails()[i].IsSelected()) {
                self.AdminToolDetails()[i].IsSelected(false);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Please tell me how to handle the checkbox event for the table header input.

Comment: as per the given code it should work fine check the fiddle sample here http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/24726/ . check for console errors and let us know, cheers

Comment: same function is working for other check boxes but not this. I tried other various options. But not sure why this is not hitting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yikes! **Don't mix manipulating the DOM with jQuery and Knockout like that.** With KnockoutJS, try to run all your logic and changes on the view models, and let the library handle updating / updates from the view.

Here's how to do this with KO:

```js
var Item = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.isSelected = ko.observable(false);
};

var Root = function() {
  var self = this;
  
  self.items = ko.observableArray([new Item("Abc"), new Item("Xyz")]);
  
  self.selectAll = ko.computed({
    read: function() { 
      return self.items().every(function(i) { return !!i.isSelected(); }) 
    },
    write: function(newVal) {
      self.items().forEach(function(i) { i.isSelected(newVal); });
    }
  });
};
                               
ko.applyBindings(new Root());
```

```css
th { border-bottom: 1px solid gray; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr class="cont-subhead trClinicList">
      <th>
          <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selectAll" />
      </th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
    <tr>
      <td class="tWidth10 textAlign">
          <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isSelected" />
      </td>
      <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This one uses [a writable computed observable](http://a%20writable%20computed%20observable), which also allows you to easily update the checkbox (view) if individual textboxes get (de)selected.

I've chosen this approach in my example because you initially use the `change` event. If you however prefer to use a click handler, you could do the same thing along these lines:

```js
var Item = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.isSelected = ko.observable(false);
};

var Root = function() {
  var self = this;
  
  self.items = ko.observableArray([new Item("Abc"), new Item("Xyz")]);
  
  self.allSelected = ko.computed(function() { 
    return self.items().every(function(i) { return !!i.isSelected(); }) 
  });
  
  self.toggleAllSelected = function(viewModel, event) {
    var newVal = !self.allSelected();
    self.items().forEach(function(i) { i.isSelected(newVal); });
    return true; // So the browser won't also handle "click" and uncheck the input again
  };
};
                               
ko.applyBindings(new Root());
```

```css
th { border-bottom: 1px solid gray; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr class="cont-subhead trClinicList">
      <th>
          <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: allSelected, click: $root.toggleAllSelected" />
      </th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
    <tr>
      <td class="tWidth10 textAlign">
          <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isSelected" />
      </td>
      <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

No DOM manipulation needed anywhere, this is all handled by Knockout (which is what it's mainly for). Added benefit: your view models are highly testable (e.g. it's easy to write unit tests for `selectAll`, etc).

Comment: this is also I have tried already , but not working. whatever it is, not hitting the function

Comment: Could be, but this does answer the question as you asked it though. If you have a specific version of your app utilizing the technique I also used I suggest asking a new question with a short repro for that scenario.